# How to add two FrameLayout in single screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I am developing a UI and I just want to add two FrameLayout in a single activity. I want one FrameLayout to be fill parent(Full Screen) layout and another FrameLayout to be on first layout. Mainly I want to make rounded circle fixed in entire application on each screen.

[image]
[image]

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/home_menu"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dis__menu"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gallery_menu"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/download_menu"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price_menu"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/feedb_menu"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>

       </LinearLayout>
       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/container_body"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1">
       </FrameLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
```

Above code dividing the screen in two parts, I want to place menus on container body FrameLayout.

Comment: I have tried with two frame layout in Linear layout. Buy I want to show one frame layout in full screen and another on it for menus

Answer (score 0):

use Relative layout instead of linear layout as the parent layout and don't nest layout too much it will take more time to render for nested layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"></FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blockBtnColor"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dis__menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/download_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/price_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/feedb_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

try this.